# Starting the year with september equinox

Tags: time-keeping, seasons

I know of several historical and fictional traditions which use spring equinox as a way to sync their calendars with the solar year, starting a new year on (or around) March 20.

Are there are any examples of real or fictional cultures that have their new years near autumn equinox, so around September 20? I imagine this would be coinciding with various harvest rituals.

Also, what could be the reasons to start a year while going into its, arguably, hardest season?

Comment: It's your world. You can start the year whenever you wish. For example the school system starts the "academic year" in September because it suits their purposes.

Comment: Here's a full list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_calendars I'm sure you can find an example with enough reading time. Maybe even edit the wiki page to include the year start/stop/length and make it more useful?

Comment: There might be a worldbuilding question here. The first half seems unimportant (are there example calendars? Does that matter?). The second - justification for doing it - that might be worldbuilding. Are you designing a world at the beginning of its calendar-building age, or is it more technologically advanced (for example, today most people don't even know where the various calendars came from or that "December" came from the Romans and literally meant "10th month"). What's the worldbuilding context here? Thanks.

Comment: *"What could be the reasons to start a year while going into its, arguably, hardest season":* some people do live in the southern hemishere. For them, the southward equinox falls in spring and the northward equinox falls in autumn.

Comment: A quick look doesn't show any examples, but looking at this from Earth's perspective - 20th September is the start of spring on the southern hemisphere. This is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### French Republican Calendar

Starts exactly on the autumn equinox -
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Republican_calendar

Hasn't been used since 1805.

#### Also:

The Ethipopian calendar starts on 11th or 12th of September - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethiopian_calendar

The Macedonian calendar started in the nearest moon of October - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Macedonian_calendar

The first month of the Coptic calendar includes the September solstice - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coptic_calendar

There are dozens I've never even heard of listed here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_calendars

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any culture that would start the year on the autumnal equinox. French Republican Calendar is not really an exception since it starts [on a day of the official proclamation of the Republic](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/French_Republican_calendar#/Calendar_design) (22 September 1792). The start of the following years was to be determined based on the time of the closest astronomical event, which happened to be the autumnal equinox. Astronomical events are used by all calendars (solar, lunar, and mixed) for various adjustments since the astronomical year and day are slightly longer than the calendar year and day.

For a culture to start a year on the autumnal equinox two conditions should be met:

1. this culture should use a [solar calendar](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Solar_calendar);
2. the autumnal equinox should be associated with one of the most important aspects of this culture or tradition.

Solar calendars are usually used by cultures that worship Sun as their main deity or have Sun god/goddess higher in their pantheon's hierarchy than a Lunar deity. These cultures are more likely to be agricultural societies since agricultural seasons align with Solar cycles.

As for the second condition, the significance of the autumnal equinox can be associated with important events (the nation was founded on this date, like in France) or worship of death and decay. The latter would probably lead to a wider used calendar for longer periods. Event-based calendars tend to disappear once the events lose their relevance.

If you go worship route, you should be careful in avoiding night worship. Cultures that worship night are more likely to follow lunar calendars. Death and decay might be more appropriate because the autumnal equinox marks the beginning of shorter days, longer nights, and eventual winter.